# Reactjs rodando em apache

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache, react

Tenho a seguinte estrutura para exibir o famoso Hello World com reactjs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>          
  </head>
  <body>                   

     <div id="root"></div>  

     <script type="text/babel">
         ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Hello World</h1>,
                document.getElementById('root')
         );
     </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Estou usando a versão mais recente do xampp e usando netbeans como IDE com o plugin php.
Quando executo o projeto aparece no navegador a página em branco. Haveria algum erro no código?

Apareceu esse erro no console (agora que vi):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tem algum erro no Console do navegador?

Comment: Comente o import do babel e veja se funciona

Answer (score 1):

O código não rodou por causa da versão do babel core. As versões 6.1 até a mais recente apresentam o erro da imagem postada; das versões 6.0.0 a 6.0.20, o conteúdo não é exibido; das versões anteriores a 6.0.0, o conteúdo é totalmente exibido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço àqueles que ajudaram; por enquanto problema relativo a isso foi resolvido!